# Submit code for execution to all processes in a concurrent.futures.ProcessPool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

Context:

- A Python application server that uses a `concurrent.futures.process.ProcessPool` to execute code
- We sometimes want to hot reload imported code without restarting the entire server process

(yes I know `importlib.reload` has [caveats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload))

To get this to work I imagine I would have to execute the `importlib.reload` in every `multiprocessing` process that is managed by the process pool.

Is there a way to submit something to **all** processes in a process pool?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how this will play out with the hot reloading attempt you mentioned, but the general question you really asked is answerable.

> Is there a way to submit something to all processes in a process pool?

The challenge here lies in assuring that really all processes get this `something` once and only once and no further execution takes place until every process got it.

You can get this type of necessary synchronization with help of a [`multiprocessing.Barrier(parties[, action[, timeout]])`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier). The barrier will hold back parties calling `barrier.wait()` until every party has done so and then release them all at once.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def foo(x):
    for _ in range(int(42e4)):
        pass
    return x


def reload(something):
    print(f"{mp.current_process().name} --- reloading {something} and waiting.")
    barrier.wait()
    print(f"{mp.current_process().name} --- released.")


def init_barrier(barrier):
    globals()['barrier'] = barrier


if __name__ == '__main__':

    MAX_WORKERS = 4
    barrier = mp.Barrier(MAX_WORKERS)

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(
            MAX_WORKERS, initializer=init_barrier, initargs=(barrier,)
    ) as executor:
        print(list(executor.map(foo, range(10))))
        # then something for all processes
        futures = [executor.submit(reload, "something") for _ in range(MAX_WORKERS)]
        for f in futures:
            f.result()

        print(list(executor.map(foo, range(10))))
```

Example Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
ForkProcess-3 --- reloading something and waiting.
ForkProcess-2 --- reloading something and waiting.
ForkProcess-1 --- reloading something and waiting.
ForkProcess-4 --- reloading something and waiting.
ForkProcess-1 --- released.
ForkProcess-4 --- released.
ForkProcess-3 --- released.
ForkProcess-2 --- released.
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If you are okay with keeping `barrier` a global and `multiprocessing.get_context()._name` returns `"fork"`, you don't need to use the `initializer` because globals will be inherited and accessible through forking.

Comment: In your example you have already waited for all outstanding tasks (submitted to `foo`) to complete, which you should do before submitting to `reload`, and now you are waiting for all task submitted to `reload` to complete, which you should do, before submitting further tasks (to `foo`). So it's not clear to me what purpose here the barrier serves.

Comment: @Booboo The barrier assures that really all processes get the `reload` by preventing a process to get the same task more than once. Without the barrier you don't know how many processes really end up executing the task (depends on OS-scheduling and how long the task takes).

Comment: So I think the point I was missing is that you are saying that `Barrier(MAX_WORKERS)` requires that MAX_WORKERS *separate* processes must make a call to `wait` before `wait` returns thus guaranteeing each process does the reload. I thought `wait` returned immediately with a count. Pretty silly.

Comment: @Booboo 
Well yeah, a process/worker is always separate. OP is essentially asking how to run an `initializer` multiple times after the processes have already started. Comment the `barrier.wait()` out and run it a couple of times. You'll eventually get to see an output where a worker doesn't reload because another did the task twice.